# Trouble with Angular material Layouts

Tags: html, angular-material

[image]I am trying to use Angular Material's Layout features to have 2 input fields in a row.

Here is my code:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center">
        <div>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Text 1</label>
                <input ng-model="query1">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Text 2</label>
                <input ng-model="query2">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have the css and js dependancies of material angular and the material angular lib itself in my index.html

```
<!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 1.0.7 used here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 1.0.7 used here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Also, when i run my app I can see the fancy floating label and it is 'glows' blue when I select the text box, so I know I have added angular material lib correctly.

My question: 
Why do my input containers appear one below the other when I have set the layout as row.

Comment: http://codepen.io/next1/pen/aNgqBb It is working properly.

Comment: its not working for me, any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Is there any parent container there? plus in your image labels are `Text 1` and `Text 2` and in the code it's `Text one` and `Text two` so is this the right code for that image?

Comment: Updated code to match text in screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may fix your problem. The comment says it's using CSS v1.0.7 but links v0.11.2, which was beta.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.css">
```